# Split the data for a time series regressions

Tags: r, time-series

I have annual data. I need to split the data and run separate regressions for each subset.

In my case, I have the following variables: gov spending, output growth and a dummy for recession in the economy (=1 if expansion, and =0 if recession).

Part of my data is shown below:

```
obs  output      gov        recession <br/>
1 0.00882917   0.039961003  0  <br/>
2 0.015555371  0.229567089  1  <br/>
3 0.023108089 -0.032468535  1  <br/>
4 0.083470801  0.282564584  0  <br/>
5 0.181719693  1.523028403  1  <br/>
6 0.171951664  1.44379044   0  <br/>
7 0.124292839  -0.55404903  0  <br/>
8 0.138767158  -1.446050184 1  <br/>
9 -0.137507301 -0.276697354 1  <br/>
10 -0.07396658 -0.5196439   1  <br/>
11 0.026799992 -0.13379183  0  <br/>
12 0.000107547 -0.053192635 0  <br/>
13 0.017405451 -0.027499262 1   <br/>
14 0.004882142  -0.0077849  0  <br/>
15 -0.017568837 0.030565404 1  <br/>
```

I need to run the following model:

***output = L1(output) + gov + L1(gov)***

I need to run this regression twice, once when `recession = 1` and once when `recession = 0`. The problem is the lags. So if in year 2000 `recession = 1` and in year 2001 `recession = 0`, when I run the model for the subset `recession = 0`, I need the lag to be taken as year 2000.

I tried to use the `dynlm' package. According to this package the lags are written as follows:

"An example would be d(y) ~ L(y, 2), where d(x, k) is diff(x, lag = k) and L(x, k) is lag(x, lag = -k), note the difference in sign. The default for k is in both cases 1. For L(), it can also be vector-valued, e.g., y ~ L(y, 1:4)"

I put my variables in a data frame and tried running the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(ts(output), ts(gov), recession)

model <- dynlm( output ~ lag(output,-1) + gov + lag(gov,-1), data=df, subset = df$recession==1)
summary(model)
```

But it gives me an error saying

> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = nomatch, ...) : 
>     'match' requires vector arguments

The problem happens when I subset the data. Because If I do not add the last option for the data subset, I get the code running and giving me the correct answer
Any idea how to do this?

Comment: did you try omit the NA values in your data ? `df <- na.omit(df)`

Comment: I do not have any missing values... the missing values will only be generated when the lags are taken!

Comment: R questions to SO should be reproducible.  See [mcve] for more info on how to ask a question.

Comment: Please also mention the packages (if any that you are using). Is `dyn$lm` correct syntax? I think `lag` should be `lag(var, 1)`.

Comment: @Imo: The syntax is correct because it is working perfectly when I do not subset the data... the problem happens with the subset...

Answer (score 0):

A crude and inefficient way to do EXACTLY what you're asking for:

```
   library( zoo ) 
   output <- read.csv( "rectest.csv" ) 
   outTS <- zoo( output, output$obs ) 
   lagOutTS <- lag( outTS, -1 ) 
   lts <- merge( outTS, lagOutTS ) 
   model <- lm( output.outTS ~ output.lagOutTS + gov.outTS + gov.lagOutTS, data=lts, subset=recession.outTS==1 )
```

Results:

```
   lm(formula = output.outTS ~ output.lagOutTS + gov.outTS + gov.lagOutTS, 
    data = lts, subset = recession.outTS == 1)

   Coefficients:
    (Intercept)  output.lagOutTS        gov.outTS     gov.lagOutTS  

    0.03201          0.88965         -0.03083          0.18854
```

But I would use an autoregressive model to do that...